# Putting the settings.xml also inside the project root dir leads to IOException during a Maven build

Tags: java, maven

In Eclipse, when I duplicate my **settings.xml** file and put it inside the project root dir as well, it creates a **.cache** folder for that project and reads the dependencies from there, instead from the local Maven repo (the **.m2** folder, where I also have the same settings.xml at the same time). This results in "IOException: when zipping The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file -> [Help 1]". This happens also if I point to the exact settings.xml file from the Eclipse Maven GUI before executing the build. Maven somehow neglects the settings.xml, that is inside the .m2 dir. It seems, that the project settings.xml has a higher priority. Why is this happening ?

Comment: Sorry, but most of this does not make sense at all. Maven looks for the `settings.xml` in the `.m2` directory unless you tell it to use a different one, e.g. that from the project. Dependencies are stored in `.m2/repository` unless the `settings.xml` defines something else.

Comment: Exactly, it does not make sense to look at the project dir for the settings.xml, while you have pointed to the settings.xml in the .m2 folder. Try to reproduce it if you dont believe me!

Comment: The problem is that the dependencies are read from the project cache, but not from the .m2 cache and in my case certain .tmp files get locked while zipping the jar file.

Comment: First try to run your build from plain command line...the zip file parts looks more like a problem with downloading and not having defined checksum policy.

Comment: @code4fun You probably added some strange configuration to your Eclipse or you misunderstood something. My eclipse does not try to read a settings.xml from my project directory.

Comment: @khmarbaise well it doesn't make difference if you try it from the command line, but you're right, that the lock fails after downloading the zip. And Maven downloads it, because it is not found inside the project .cache folder, however it should look for it inside the .m2 cache instead...

Comment: It makes a big differences cause on plain command we have no influence of Eclipse to cleanly separate the problems. Is it an issue of Eclipse or is there an issue in Maven/Configuration. Apart from that there is no project `.cache` in Maven. The cache for Maven is `$HOME/.m2/repository` that's it..so best would having an example project that shows the issue?

Comment: @khmarbaise well, there IS a project .cache folder in my case and it gets auto-generated on build, but only when you have a settings.xml within the project dir. There is also a .cache folder under the local Maven repository. If you want to reproduce this scenario, download the AxonIvy BPM studio, it is based on Eclipse, create an Ivy project and put a settings.xml to the root project dir. Then run a Maven build, preffered goals would be Clean Install.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I put a settings.xml in the project root dir, but I don't want Eclipse to use it. I never told it explicitely to use that file, but it does use it. Is there a possibility to change this behaviour?